# Efficient divide-and-conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm

At a political event, introducing 2 people determines if they represent the same party or not.
Suppose more than half of the n attendees represent the same party. I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm that will identify the representatives of this party using as few introductions as possible.

A brute force solution will be to maintain two pointers over the array of attendees, introducing n attendees to n-1 other attendees in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time. I can't figure out how to improve on this.

Edit: Formally,

```
You are given an integer n. There is a hidden array A of size n, such that more than half of the values in A are the same. This array represents the party affiliation of each person.

You are allowed queries of the form introduce(i, j), where i≠j, and 1 <= i, j <= n, and you will get a boolean value in return: You will get back 1, if A[i] = A[j], and 0 otherwise.

Output: B ⊆ [1, 2. ... n] where |B| > n/2 and the A-value of every element in B is the same.
```

Hopefully this explains the problem better.

Comment: I didn't fully understand the question, but is *disjoint-set* what you need?

Comment: I don't think so - I have edited the post to try to explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: Just do a first pass of Quicksort in O(n), that's sufficient to divide an array into two sets that aren't equal in size.

Comment: It even makes me more puzzled. It sounds like you only needs to store a something like hash map and implement this in `O(n)` time, you even don't need quick sort

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Why is quicksort `O(n)`? Quicksort is not a linear algorithm.

Comment: @JohnDing I said first pass of Quicksort, which is sufficient for a binary division in O(n) time, not full Quicksort which is O(n log n) average.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I understood. You mean something like `std::partition` in C++.

Comment: Sorry, my second explanation was completely wrong. I've changed it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in O(n) introductions using the [Boyer–Moore majority vote algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm#Description).

Consider some arbitrary ordering of the attendees: A_1, A_2, ..., A_n. In the algorithm, you maintain a 'stored element', denoted by m. Whenever the algorithm wants to check if the current element (x) is same as the stored element or not, you introduce those two people and increment or decrement the counter accordingly. The stored element at the end will be a member of the majority party. Then, you can do another pass over all the other n - 1 people, and introduce each of them to this known person and hence find all the members of the majority party.

Thus, the total number of introductions is O(n).