# Efficient algorithm to calculate the mode of a hidden array

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm trying to solve the extension to a problem I described in my question: [Efficient divide-and-conquer algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037375/efficient-divide-and-conquer-algorithm)
For this extension, there is known to be representatives for 3 parties at the event, and there are more members for 1 party attending than for any other. A formal description of the problem can be found below.

You are given an integer n. There is a hidden array A of size n, which contains elements that can take 1 of 3 values. There is a value, let this be m, that appears more often in the array than the other 2 values.
You are allowed queries of the form introduce(i, j), where i≠j, and 1 <= i, j <= n, and you will get a boolean value in return: You will get back 1, if A[i] = A[j], and 0 otherwise.
Output: B ⊆ [1, 2. ... n] where the A-value of every element in B is m.

A brute-force solution to this could calculate B in O(n<sup>2</sup>) by calling introduce(i, j) on n(n-1) combinations of elements and create 3 lists containing A-indexes of elements for which a 1 was returned when introduce was called on them, returning the list of largest size.
I understand the [Boyer–Moore majority vote algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm) but can't find a way to modify it for this problem or find an efficient algorithm to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan for all A[i] = A[0], and make list I[] of all i for which A[i] != A[0].  Then scan for all A[I[j]] = A[I[0]], and so on.  Which requires one O(n) scan for each possible value in A[].

[I assume if *introduce(i, j) = 1* and *introduce(j, k) = 1*, then *introduce(i, k) = 1* -- so you don't need to check all combinations of elements.]

Of course, this doesn't tell you what 'm' is, it just makes *n* lists, where *n* is the number of values, and each list is all the 'i' where A[i] is the same.